# invalid HTML rendering logic

Tags: html

Nearly all browsers use a certain amount of leeway in rendering invalid HTML.  For example, they would render `x < y` as if it were written `x &lt; y` because it is "clear" that the `<` is intended as a literal character, not part of an HTML tag.

Where can I find that logic as a separate "cleanup" module? Such a module would convert `x < y` to `x &lt; y`

Comment: What are you using it for? If you're rendering user-content, it would be better to escape the who thing and output it. If you're writing a rendering engine... Good luck.

Comment: I am rendering user content, but I want to retain certain "safe" tags.  I'm already using a module that removes "unsafe" tags, but it's also removing invalid HTML that looks like an unrecognized tag.  I want to "clean it up" before handing it over to the module.

Comment: Check my answer, you can do this without any modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the source code for [Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/).

HTML before running through Tidy:

```
<html>

 <head>
  <title>boo</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   x < y
 </body>

</html>
```

Same HTML after running through Tidy:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">

  <title>boo</title>
</head>

<body>
  x &lt; y
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that `x < y` was changed to `x &lt; y`.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, you should probably use Tidy to clean up your HTML. I believe there are Tidy libraries for most of the common languages, that will clean up your HTML for you. If you are using PHP, there is [PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

**UPDATE**

I noticed that you said you're using C#. You can use Tidy with C# as well. Here's something I found. I don't develop in C# and I haven't tried this out so YMMV:

[Fix Up Your HTML with HTML Tidy and .NET](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/20505/1763/page/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean exactly, but maybe the PHP function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) could help you.

Comment: No... see my response to @Mike Caron's comment

Answer (score 0):

Rendering of invalid HTML in browsers is horrible guesswork, and you really shouldn't try to emulate it (it *will* break). However, replacing some occurrences could be done with a regexp:

```
preg_replace('/(\s)<(\s)/', '$1&lt;$2', $data);
```

Comment: This will change ` < body>` to ` &lt; body>`. Undesirable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Vivin: It is. It relies to a certain extent on users formatting their input properly, but it's fairly good. @Chuck: We're not actually parsing HTML here, but yeah.

Comment: I tend to be more paranoid :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML 5 (draft) specification includes [a detailed parsing algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html#parsing) based on how browsers handle bad markup.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I am assuming you're using PHP, since you didn't specify

Use strip_tags:

```
$content = strip_tags($content, array('<b><i>'));
```

This will leave safe tags (as defined by you), and remove everything else.

Comment: I'm not using PHP, but I'm using something similar to strip_tags in C#.  The problem is that my "strip_tags" thinks that "x < y" contains an unknown (and unterminated) tag called "y" and it "strips" it, leaving just "x"

Comment: @David It's the most common web development language. And, everyone else assumed that too. The onus is on the OP to specify, right?

Comment: @Joel Ah, in that case, I'd go with someone else's answer. Vivin's is the only one with a C# answer, so... yeah.

Comment: @David, PHP is the most common language. OP should specify or at least tag his question, otherwise you need to make these assumptions.